# How to do a group by in Grafana using Log queries?

Tags: grafana

I have a query which gives me all the `HTTP 503` errors in the namespace:

`({namespace="test-1da4092d"} |~ "HTTP 503")`

Now, i would like to count number of `HTTP 503`s for each `container`, and i used the below query:

`count by(container) ({namespace="test-1da4092d"} |~ "HTTP 503")`

However i got the error as below:
[image]